# Rails: cat log/production.log not giving error log

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to check errors on my server. I am running this command on server console:

```
    cat log/production.log
```

But instead of showing error log, it gives long compilation list.

```
 Compiled rails_admin/ra.remote-form.js  (0ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/jquery.pjax.js  (0ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/ra.nested-form-hooks.js  (20ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/ra.widgets.js  (84ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/ui.js  (35ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/custom/ui.js  (0ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/rails_admin.js  (407ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/jquery.colorpicker.css  (34ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled font-awesome.css  (84ms)  (pid 20531)
 Compiled rails_admin/rails_admin.css  (4245ms)  (pid 20531)
 ..........................
```

I am not getting why it is not producing error log and giving all compiled list.

Can anyone tell how to check errors?

I will really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any clues?

Comment: Please post any solutions